# Linking 2 collections using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to link 2 collections together by saving a reference between them, but I'm stuck on how to push into the array. I have the following schemas:

**Company schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  projects: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project'
  }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('company', companySchema, 'companies')
```

**Project schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  company: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('project', projectSchema, 'projects')
```

**My create Project router looks like this**

```
router.post('/create', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    let project = new Project({ name: req.body.name, company: req.body.company })
    await project.save()
    res.status(201).send({ project })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'Server error while creating project'
    })
  }
})
```

It's correctly creating the `Project`. But now I need it to also push the newly created `Project` into the `projects` array of the `Company` schema. Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like you want to reference the projects associated with the company than actually add references to those projects. For this to happen you will need to store the company's `id` into your new project, which I hope is what your `req.body.company` field represents.

Once each new project contains a valid `companyId`, you might want to check the list of projects associated with that same company. For this, you need to populate a virtual field in your company document:

```
companySchema.virtual('projects', {
  ref: 'Projects',
  localField: 'id',
  foreignField: 'companyId'
})
```

Of course, this would only work if you rephrase your schemas a little bit:

```
const companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  companyId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
  }
})
```

Finally, whenever you want to check a company's projects, you will have to populate the projects field with `companyDocument.populate('projects').execPopulate()`. This way, `companyDocument.projects` will contain the array you're looking for.